# Flutter sms_autofill plugin is conflicting with razorpay_flutter

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, flutter-dependencies, razorpay

I'm trying to use the following two Flutter plugin in my flutter project.

[razorpay_flutter 1.1.2](https://pub.dev/packages/razorpay_flutter)

[sms_autofill 1.2.0](https://pub.dev/packages/sms_autofill/)

My Flutter code -

```
_askPhone() async {
    const MethodChannel _channel = const MethodChannel('sms_autofill');
    String phoneNo = await _channel.invokeMethod('requestPhoneHint');
    print(phoneNo);
    setState(() => _phone = phoneNo);
}
```

I'm trying to use only `requestPhoneHint` method through `platform-channel` to ask phone number from user. But alone **sms_autofill** plugin is working fine in this case but when I added **razorpay_flutter** plugin to my dependency it only prompts phone number but nothing happens on selecting.
   Problem is that `String phoneNo = await _channel.invokeMethod('requestPhoneHint');` line doesn't returns anything now. From my experience I think that it is probably might be due to duplicate request code in `startIntentSenderForResult` method in these both plugin so I tried changing that but still no result.

P.S. - I would like to make changes in **sms_autofill** plugin, please suggest anything.

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed by modifying razorpay_flutter 1.1.2 plugin to return false from inactivity result when requestCode is for sms_autofill plugin.